# Image size messed up when running website on a mobile device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have an image that I want to display behind some text. It works fine when I open the website on my desktop browser. Even going into mobile mode from console does not show any problems. However, after deploying the website, when I open it on an actual mobile device, the image is stretched out.

I tried making width and height auto and allowing max-width to be 100% but screws up the image in other ways.

This is how it shows on desktop https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yyta.png.
This is how it shows on cellphone mode in chrome console https://i.stack.imgur.com/kORcg.png
But this is how it shows on an actual mobile device [https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ftSy.jpg[https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ftSy.jpg][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ftSy.jpg%5Bhttps://i.stack.imgur.com/9ftSy.jpg%5D%5B1%5D)

HTML

```
<div class="row d-flex text-center justify-content-center pb-4 footerWithImage">
            <div class="row mt-4 d-block text-white col-lg-5">
                <!-- Content -->
                <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Carson Moore Fitness</h6>
                <hr class="bg-light mb-4 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto" style="width: 60px;">
                <p>Helping clients build muscle, burn fat and improve posture using safe and effective,
                    personalized fitness programs.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-4 d-block text-white col-lg-5 footerContacts">

                <!-- Links -->
                <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Contact</h6>
                <hr class="bg-light mb-4 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto" style="width: 60px;">
                <br>
                <a href="https://g.page/sandcastlefitnessclub-24hrs?share"><i class="fas fa-home mr-3"></i>White Rock,
                    Surrey, BC</a><br>
                <a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top"><i
                        class="far fa-envelope mr-3"></i>&nbsp;info@carsonmoorefitness.com</a><br>
                <a href="tel:604-555-5555"><i class="fas fa-phone mr-3"></i>+16045555555</a>
                <div id="socialMediaLinksDiv">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.footerWithImage {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563685759732-3b118f9445c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 20%;    
}
```

**Note**: It's solved. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57477984/5840458)

Comment: Looks like the image URL call is passing parameters you may not control with your CSS, try to remove everything beyond the first "?" in your image URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to target that image using media queries to specify the size you want on mobile.

Comment: Here's what solved it:

`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) {
 .footerWithImage {
  background-attachment: scroll;
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put `!important` after `background` styles as a lot of browsers/frameworks will overwrite your custom styling e.g. `background-size: cover;`

```
.footerWithImage {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563685759732-3b118f9445c3");
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center 20% !important;    
}
```

Read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-apply-important-in-css/)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `max-width` property allows the image to maintain its exact aspect ratio and proportions, making it a great fit for responsive web design.

Here’s how the CSS code would look:

```css
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Now just adjust the percentage according to your need.

Answer (score -2):

I'm posting it here again, so people can see it more but [Singh Raman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464250/image-size-messed-up-when-running-website-on-a-mobile-device/77547906#comment101647592_57464314) works great.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) {     
.footerWithImage {      
   background-attachment: scroll;} 
}
```